# PHP XML Parse from website URL

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I've got a XML file on the net which I'm trying to split up into variables and display to the user.

This is the url to the file:
    http://www.labs.skanetrafiken.se/v2.2/querypage.asp?inpPointFr=lund&inpPointTo=ystad

This now seems VERY easy to do from what I've read but the only thing I've gotten to work is this.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);
echo $xml->asXML(); // this spits out a huuuge string.
```

*Nothing* else has worked. Not simplexml_load_string() or any of the other things.

I've read about 20-40 tutorials and none have worked, getting abit frustrated so to speak.

Comment: For a URL, you need `simplexml_load_file()`.

Comment: I just tried: 
"$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
var_dump($xml);"
And got the output = "object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { } "

Comment: Yeah, you have a SimpleXMLElement object - Now you have to parse it.

Comment: I did this now: "$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);
$obj = simplexml_load_file($xml); var_dump($obj);" And got the output = "bool(false)"

Comment: Tried also: "$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true); $obj = simplexml_load_string($xml); var_dump($obj);" And got the output = "bool(false)"

Comment: possible you can reference `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194489/how-to-parse-soap-xml`

Comment: Still struggling, SOAP stuff just ain't working either for me!

Comment: Just answered my own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861081/php-how-to-link-soap-xml-with-xml-schema-xsd/11863994#11863994