# Parsing SOAP response from server

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

Can anybody help me with parsing soap response. I tried a lot of many ways, but thats didn't help me. Im stucked.
There is response:

```
  <soap:envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:body>
    <ns2:findflightresponse xmlns:ns2="http://cxf.apache.org">
      <return>
        <clstobook>K</clstobook>
        <flightsegment>
          <arrivalairport>
            <locationcode>LHR</locationcode>
            <terminal>1</terminal>
          </arrivalairport>
          <arrivaldatetime>2013-09-01T16:15:00</arrivaldatetime>
          <bookingclassavaillist>
            <resbookdesigcode>W</resbookdesigcode>
            <resbookdesigquantity>0</resbookdesigquantity>
            <resbookdesigstatuscode>3</resbookdesigstatuscode>
            <rph>1</rph>
          </bookingclassavaillist>
          <bookingclassavaillist>
            <resbookdesigcode>U</resbookdesigcode>
            <resbookdesigquantity>0</resbookdesigquantity>
            <resbookdesigstatuscode>2</resbookdesigstatuscode>
            <rph>1</rph>
          </bookingclassavaillist>
          <departureairport>
            <locationcode>VKO</locationcode>
          </departureairport>
          <departuredatetime>2013-09-01T15:10:00</departuredatetime>
          <equipment>
            <airequiptype>738</airequiptype>
          </equipment>
          <flightnumber>353</flightnumber>
          <marketingairline>
            <code>UN</code>
          </marketingairline>
          <marketingcabin>
            <meal>B</meal>
          </marketingcabin>
          <rph>1</rph>
          <stopquantity>0</stopquantity>
        </flightsegment>
        <lateforsale>false</lateforsale>
        <noseats>false</noseats>
      </return>
    </ns2:findflightresponse>
  </soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

ive tried like:

```
$xml_response = $ch_result;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_response,NULL,NULL,"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns2', 'http://cxf.apache.org');
print_r($xml);
```

but, it returns:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Body] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
```

I never work with xml files. Thats my first practice with xml soap, and i didnt have got a lot of knowledge.
can anybody help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse SOAP XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194489/how-to-parse-soap-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
        $xml = str_replace("soap:", "", $xml);
        $xml = str_replace("ns2:", "", $xml);
        $xml = str_replace("ns3:", "", $xml);
        $xml = str_replace("&#0", "", $xml);

        $array = xml2array($xml);
        $array = $array['envelope']['body']['findflightresponse'];

        print_r($array, true);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but print_r($array, true); returns nothing :(
tried var_dump($array); it returns NULL.

Comment: The function you've used is from a malware site. I've removed it. Also the suggestion you give just means that you have no clue what XML Namespaces are. Your answer is actually standing in the way so that @user2736875 can learn something. Instead you have shown bad practice. Try to find out how XML Namespaces work and which XML parsers PHP has to offer. There is no reason at all to convert this into an array.

Comment: And if you're doing this because you're lazy, then please just link to an existing answer that shows what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @hakre well, 1st off thanks for info. im not PHP expert and if it works for me, it can work for someone who is looking for quick answer. No one answered till now. For sure, answer from Guru like you with your experience is more appreciated. I'll give you +1 if you post your right answer. Thanks. BTW, I took it from my site and not googled it

Comment: No worries, It's a duplicate and I already voted to close against.