# Parsing a soap response and displays a web url

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am trying to parse the SOAP response of this XML:

```
$xml_body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                 <soap:Body>
                    <Interop_PushResponse xmlns="http://sample.org/webservices/">
                      <Interop_PushResult>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;Response Code="200"&gt;&lt;Description&gt;Update completed successfully&lt;/Description&gt;&lt;URL&gt;/Patient/PatientView.aspx?pid=96&lt;/URL&gt;&lt;/Response&gt;
                      </Interop_PushResult>
                    </Interop_PushResponse>
                  </soap:Body>
              </soap:Envelope>';
```

What I am trying to do is to get the `<URL>` tag value /Patient/PatientView.aspx?pid=96 and add it to a certain web URL, then display the complete URL address upon successful SOAP request and response cycle. I've tried doing what is instructed here in [How to parse SOAP XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194489/how-to-parse-soap-xml) but it doesnt work on me it shows no response. I am badly need help.
TIA.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194489/how-to-parse-soap-xml

Comment: Hi Alexandr Kapustin, I've tried doing the solution on that page but it doesn't work on me. it doesn't show any result.