# Get information from string with a wsdl in PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

and it returns this:

```
<soap:Header>
  <wsim:WSEAuthenticateHeader>
     <wsim:Usser>?</wsim:Usser>
     <wsim:Password>?</wsim:Password>
  </wsim:WSEAuthenticateHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <wsim:postScormRequest>
     <wsim:item1></wsim:item1>
     <wsim:item2></wsim:item2>
     <wsim:item3></wsim:item3>
  </wsim:postScormRequest>
</soap:'... (length=535)
```

How can I get the information of the user, password and items?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to parse SOAP XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194489/how-to-parse-soap-xml) .  The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24085540/5517065) should work for your purpose.

Comment: You were using the PHP `SoapClient` in your other questions. Why not use that here?

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is incomplete, as we talk on comments

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I can't use nusoap... I try to use simplexml whit `$obj = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

var_dump ($obj);` and say _object(SimpleXMLElement)[58]_ and try to cast to string `var_dump ((string) $obj);` and say _string '
   
   
' (length=9)_

Comment: There is something wrong with your payload. Where is the XML root tag (soap envelope) and its name Spaces?

Comment: Oh... you are rigth... the xml was wrong... When I fix it I can manage with SimpleXMLElement. Thanks a lot