# How to print a Soap XML object using php

Tags: php, xml, object

I need to grab and print a value of a Soap XML object using PHP.

I tried with this but I get no results:

```
echo $token->soap:envelope->soap:body->authenticationuserresponse->authenticationuserresult;
```

And also this one:

```
echo $token->envelope->body->authenticationuserresponse->authenticationuserresult;
```

Take a look at the capture to see what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Is this message coming through a normal HTTP request, or are you using the built-in [SOAP client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195132/231316) which provides ready access to these?

Comment: @ChrisHaas the xml comes from a HTTP request. Can you help me please. The duplicated question is not helping me at all. Thanks.

Comment: I’m willing to help, but you need to post some code, no screenshots. Please include the actual XML, how you are loading it, and how you are attempting to parse it.

Comment: @ChrisHaas This is the actual xml: https://www.pakot.com/AuthenticationUser3.xml I need to print out the AuthenticationToken in my screen using php 'echo'.

Comment: As noted in the answer that this was marked as a duplicate of, in order to access anything within a namespace you just need to qualify it. See this for two versions of doing that: https://3v4l.org/hUBWs. Both could use lots of checks because there's lots of places where null or incorrect index assumptions might happen, but I'll leave that to you. In the long run, seriously consider making your initial call that happens _before_ this use the native SOAP clint

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas thanks!  One last thing. I'm trying to modify your example to output each 'stocks' using a foreach() loop but I can't get it. Can you please take a look and tell me what is wrong? https://3v4l.org/LXKBE